# What can be wrong in this simple php code

Tags: php

```
$number1 = 56;
$number2 = 70;
$number3 = 12.56;

echo  "Addition of $number1 and $number2 : " . $number1 + $number2 ;
echo  "<br>";
echo "Subtraction of $number2 from $number1 but with absolute function: " . abs ($number-$number2) . "<br>";
```

when i refresh the page it gives error "A non-numeric value encountered" Any help

Comment: In your call to `abs` you refer to `$number` which is not defined.

Comment: `abs ($number-$number2)` you not define `$number`. it should be `$number1` instead of `$number`

Comment: Thanx for your answer i already correct that mistake but error was due to above adding function if i remove string then it works fine but if i add string then it gives error

Comment: @Denshen show your error

Comment: You also need to change `"Addition of $number1 and $number2 : " . $number1 + $number2 ` to `"Addition of $number1 and $number2 : " . ($number1 + $number2 )`

Comment: @Nick Thanx adding brackets solve the problem. Thanx to all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beacuse `$number` is undefined . Define it like below

```
$number1 = 56;
$number2 = 70;
$number3 = 12.56;

$number = $number1 + $number2; //define $number
echo  "Addition of $number1 and $number2 : " . $number ;
echo  "<br>";
echo "Subtraction of $number2 from $number but with absolute function: " . abs ($number-$number2) . "<br>";
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/kUVRo

***Or change your code like below***:

```
$number1 = 56;
$number2 = 70;
$number3 = 12.56;

echo  "Addition of $number1 and $number2 : " . ($number1 + $number2) ; //bracket added
echo  "<br>";
//use predefined variable instead of $number
echo "Subtraction of $number2 from $number1 but with absolute function: " . abs ($number1-$number2) . "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanx it also works. i am new so i make mistakes some times but this site is very helpful.

Comment: i can't upvote as i am new i dont have that much points answer but i mark you answer as it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

As per my comments (you not define `$number`. it should be `$number1` instead of `$number`). Also As per @nick add brackets like `($number1 + $number2)`

```
$number1 = 56;
$number2 = 70;
$number3 = 12.56;

echo  "Addition of $number1 and $number2 : " . ($number1 + $number2) ;
echo  "<br>";
echo "Subtraction of $number2 from $number1 but with absolute function: " . abs ($number1-$number2) . "<br>";
```